# Area in polar coordinates (slightly easy?)

Tags: calculus

I was looking for the area of the loop of the curve $$r^2=a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta,$$ which is bisected by the initial line. I believe this initial line is the x-axis. But what scratched my head is how to plot $r^2=a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta$ because when I plot it myself by letting $a=1$, I would get a straight line. Straight line in polar coordinates? seems unlikely.

How do you answer this above-mentioned question? Thanks! I wonder what $r^2=a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta$ look like, hehe

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+plot+y%5E2%3D%3Dcos(x)cos(2x)?

Answer (score 2):

A plot is below from Alpha.  I don't see a straight line.  There are two different sizes of loop.  Either one will yield to area$=\int \frac 12 r^2 d\theta$ giving a reasonable trigonometric integral.  The edges of the loops are $\theta=\frac \pi 4, \frac \pi 2, \frac {3\pi}4$ and their negatives.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@RossMillikan I believe this might be the correct graph of $r^2=a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta$ if we change it to $r=\sqrt {a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta}$ and letting $a=1$. I believe it doesn't matter even if $a$ will be negative.

[image]

Comment: @RossMillikan I believe this might be the correct graph of if $r^2=a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta$ and we change it to $r=\sqrt {a^2\cos2\theta \cos\theta}$ and letting a=1. I believe it doesn't matter even if $a$ will be negative.